# Handler mappings feature not available on IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, handler-mappings

I have installed IIS 7 on a Windows 2008 server and I need to enable the "Handler Mappings" feature on it.

I have already installed every single "role service" on IIS 7 but I can't seem to be able to enable the handler mappings.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the info you need should be [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240(WS.10).aspx) in TechNet.